# Android Logcat extremely slow and out of date

Tags: android, logcat

When in android studio my logcat often starts to break down. It will start slowly outputing logs, one every few seconds except the logs are uppwards of 20-30 minutes old.

This happens whenever I am debugging, whether I am using a physical or an emulated device.

How can I fix logcat so it is actually useable?

Comment: you may be looking at the top of the log output. try to scroll down?

Comment: I just closed android studio, and it takes a while for the problem to occur, but I am pretty sure that is not it.

Comment: what does it give in command line?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this on certain devices because of the large buffer for logcat outputs. Certain things you can try:

1. adb logcat -c to clear the buffer
2. Clear the logcat every time you
   run the application

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

It's been 7 years since this question was posted but it's been happening to me too when connected to a smartphone via wifi. That doesn't happen to TVs. Also, it only happens when using MacOS. I haven't experienced it in Linux so far.

I followed the recommendation [@Actiwitty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487994/10100828) gave us in his answer and it's half of the solution. What solved it to me was also restarting the logcat (the green button in the picture)

So the steps I follow to make it work are:

1. run the command `adb logcat -c`
2. restart logcat in Android Studio

[image: restarting the logcat]